# Determine absolute position of a pixel on a canvas where GDI+ offset, scaling and/or rotation transforms have been applied

Tags: delphi, transform, gdi+

I have Delphi code that draws various gauges on a canvas using GDI+. One of these gauges draws a small dot at a position relative to the center of a transformed GDI+ canvas. The GDI+ transform may include translate, rotate and/or scale.

Is it possible to determine the absolute position of that dot w.r.t. the un-transformed canvas?

```
gdi := TGPGraphics.Create(Canvas.Handle);
gdi.TranslateTransform(info.Left + info.Width div 2, info.Top + info.Height div 2);
gdi.RotateTransform(info.Angle);
ThisPoint := TGPPoint.Create(30, 10);
```

I need the magic code to perform the following...

```
AbsolutePointOnCanvas := UnTransform(ThisPoint);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the direction of transformation...

If you want to apply the same transformation, then you can call TransformPoints() to apply the transformation to an array of TGPPoints.

If you want to apply the reverse transformation, you have to compute a new transformation combination using the same transforms with `sign changed` and in `reverse order`. And then use TransformPoints to the point you want to reverse-transform.

To better separate transformation from drawing, you may use TGPMatrix to create the transformation matrix, using Multiply to combine several transformations in a single matrix. Once you get the complete transformation, you apply it using TGpGraphics.SetTransform().

You need to compute a new transformation matrix when external condidtion change (zooming, paning and others) and apply it in the drawing process.

By the way, I prefer to use Direct2D canvas instead of GDI canvas because Direct2D make use of GPU and today it is faster than GDI if properly used.

Comment: To be honest I hadn't even considered Direct2D. The application is reasonably graphics intensive so that is something I should look into. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: gdi.Transform.TransformPoint() was the obvious answer. I just couldn't see the wood for the trees. Thanks for taking the time to help.